# how to show specific rows from database on gridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to add specific rows from database to gridview by gridview column name. Please send me code for this. Or help me in my code.
[dgvSale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBKj6.jpg)

```
try
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM PackageProduct where IDs='" + id + "'";


    SqlCommand Comm11 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader DR11 = Comm11.ExecuteReader();
  while (DR11.Read())
    {



        dgvSale.Cells[1].Value = DR11["ProductName"].ToString().Trim();
        dgvSale.Cells[2].Value = DR11["ProductQty"].ToString().Trim();
        dgvSale.Cells[3].Value = DR11["Price"].ToString().Trim();
        dgvSale.Cells[4].Value = DR11["Discount"].ToString().Trim();
        dgvSale.Cells[5].Value = DR11["TotalAmount"].ToString().Trim();
    }

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    XtraMessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just an additional comment, but you should not concatenate a string value into your SQL statement, but should use parameters - lookup SqlParameter. this will avoid Sql Injection.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(DR11);
    dgvSale.DataSource = table;
    reader.Close();
```

Comment: Sir i have  six column in dgvSale but i want to add value on 5 columns.as i show on code

Comment: if you bound a gridview to a column, the value will display there, but if column not bounded then nothing will be displayed, so you can bound five columns to fields and leave one column not bounded, then after binding grid to datatable just 5 column have text...

Comment: I would also advise changing your select to only select the columns you want to display. This is much more efficient. To do this replace the * after the select with the column names separated with comma. e.g. SELECT ProductName, ProductQty, Price, Discount, TotalAmount FROM PackageProduct ...